# How can I uniquely identify textbox controls retrieved from another application?

Tags: winapi

I'm writing an application in C# to remote control another application.  I don't have access to that application yet, but it's most likely written in either Visual C++ or VB6.  I'm currently remote controlling a simple C# winforms program I created instead.  So far, I can get all of the controls in a manner similar to Spy++ using PInvoke.  I can also do things like setting the text in a textbox.  The problem I have is that I can't uniquely identify a specific text box between executions of the application I'm controlling.  I can't use hWnd for example because it's different every time you run the application.  GetWindowLong returns whatever the hWnd is so that's no help.  The internet speaks of this message called WM_GETCONTROLNAME.  The scary code below attempts to use that message to get the name the developer used to uniquely identify the controls.  The SendMessage seems like it's returning the number of bytes in the name.  But the buffer containing that name comes back all zeros.

So here's the question.  How can I fix the code below so that it returns that name correctly?  (Hopefully it's a boneheaded mistake that's easy to fix)  Or, just as good, is there some other ID that will be guaranteed to be the same every time I run the program?  Without something to uniquely identify the textbox controls, my code can't tell them apart.

I do have a hack in mind.  It seems to me that using the position of the textboxes to tell them apart would work.  But I'd much prefer to have the code below working.

```
    public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr Handle)
    {
        int BufferSize = 256;
        uint Message = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GETCONTROLNAME");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(BufferSize);
        byte[] ControlName = new byte[BufferSize];
        long BytesRead = 0;
        IntPtr BytesReadPointer = new IntPtr(BytesRead);
        IntPtr OtherMem = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            OtherMem = VirtualAllocEx(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(sb.Capacity), AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);
            var Result = SendMessage(Handle, Message, new IntPtr(sb.Capacity), OtherMem);
            //Result contains different numbers which seem like the correct lengths
            var Result2 = ReadProcessMemory(Handle, OtherMem, ControlName, BufferSize, out BytesReadPointer);
            //ControlName always comes back blank.
        }
        finally
        {
            var Result3 = VirtualFreeEx(Handle, OtherMem, BufferSize, FreeType.Release);
        }

        return ""; // Convert ControlName to a string

    }
```

Comment: Why not use automation

Comment: Alternatively, you may try to use [`GetDlgCtrlID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478(v=vs.85).aspx). Works with any parent window type, not only for dialogs.

Comment: Use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool to verify, whether your target application implements the automation interfaces. If it does, use UI Automation (instead of the appallingly complex and brittle hack you have come up with).

Answer (score -2):

So after a good night's sleep and a little tinkering, I managed to fix the problem myself.  There were two problems.  First, I was passing in the handle to the control to VirtualAllocEx.  But in the documentation for that function, it says that it takes a handle to the process.  So started supplying that.  Then VirtualAllocEx was telling me that I had an invalid handle.  So it turns out the handle you pass to VirualAllocEx has to have PROCESS_VM_OPERATION set.  So I made a call to OpenProcess to get that handle, then passed that to VirtualAllocEx.  After that, everything worked.  I just had to convert the byte array coming back into a string, and trim a bunch of nulls.  This returns the Name property on the controls.  I'll post the code here in case anyone else needs something like this.

```
    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
        VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
        VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
        DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
        CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
        SetQuota = 0x00000100,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }

    public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr ControlHandle, IntPtr ProcessHandle)
    {
        int BufferSize = 256;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(BufferSize);
        byte[] ControlNameByteArray = new byte[BufferSize];
        long BytesRead = 0;
        IntPtr BytesReadPointer = new IntPtr(BytesRead);
        IntPtr RemoteProcessMemoryAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr RemoteProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            uint Message = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GETCONTROLNAME");

            RemoteProcessHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.CreateThread |
                                              ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation |
                                              ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation |
                                              ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite |
                                              ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryRead, false, Process.Id);

            RemoteProcessMemoryAddress = VirtualAllocEx(RemoteProcessHandle, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(sb.Capacity), AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);

            if (RemoteProcessMemoryAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("GetWindowText: " + GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            SendMessage(ControlHandle, Message, new IntPtr(sb.Capacity), RemoteProcessMemoryAddress);
            ReadProcessMemory(RemoteProcessHandle, RemoteProcessMemoryAddress, ControlNameByteArray, BufferSize, out BytesReadPointer);
            string ControlName = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ControlNameByteArray).TrimEnd('\0');

            return ControlName;
        }
        finally
        {
            VirtualFreeEx(RemoteProcessHandle, RemoteProcessMemoryAddress, BufferSize, FreeType.Release);
        }
    }
```